# WITH clause in Maria DB

Tags: mysql, mariadb-10.1

I am trying to run below query in Maria DB (10.1.26-MariaDB-0+deb9u1 Debian 9.1)

```
with ind as 
(
   select index_name, 
          table_name, 
          group_concat(column_name) column_name, 
          index_type 
   from   information_schema.statistics  
   where  table_schema = 'mydb' 
   and    index_name != 'primary' 
   group by 1,2,4
) 
select concat('create index ', ind.index_name, ' on ', ind.table_name,
              '(', ind.column_name,') using ', ind.index_type, ';') 
from   ind;
```

Im running the above query and getting some syntax error. What I am missing?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: And what version are you using? MariaDB implemented [CTEs in version 10.2](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/with/)

Comment: I'm getting from ```ind as ``` till end.

Comment: If you are in 10.1, no CTEs. That's the reason ;) Upgrade

Comment: Yeah, It works after upgrading to 10.2. Thanks.